# How can I label the coordinate position of the grid coordinate lines

Tags: java, geotools, grids-graticules

I need to display the coordinates of the grid lines. I saw this article '[Fun with Graticules](https://blog.ianturton.com/geotools/mapping/cartography/2015/06/17/fun-with-graticules.html)', which has much common with that I want to do.

But I still have a question. How did you create the new instance of the CoordinateFormatter class in GeoTools?

And also, how did you overload this setAttributes function? -

```
GridFeatureBuilder grid_builder =
       new GridFeatureBuilder(GridType) {  
            @Override
            public void setAttributes(GridElement ge, Map<String, Object> map) {
                 some code...       
            }
};
```

Comment: thanks for reminding me of that code, I must chase up the licence some day.

Answer (score 2):

I created a class `LineFeatureBuilder` that extends `GridFeatureBuilder`:

```
import java.text.Format;
import java.util.Map;

import org.geotools.grid.GridElement;
import org.geotools.grid.GridFeatureBuilder;
import org.geotools.grid.ortholine.LineOrientation;
import org.geotools.grid.ortholine.OrthoLine;
import org.geotools.measure.CoordinateFormat;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;
import org.opengis.referencing.cs.CoordinateSystem;

public class LineFeatureBuilder extends GridFeatureBuilder {
  /** Default feature TYPE name: "linegrid" */
  public static final String DEFAULT_TYPE_NAME = "linegrid";

  /** Name used for the integer id attribute: "id" */
  public static final String ID_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "id";

  /**
   * Name of the Integer level attribute ("level")
   */
  public static final String LEVEL_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "level";

  /**
   * Name of the Object value attribute ("value")
   */
  public static final String VALUE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "value";

  public static final String VALUE_LABEL_NAME = "label";

  protected int id;
  private SimpleFeatureType type;
  private CoordinateFormat formatter;
  private Format xFormat;
  private Format yFormat;
  private String xUnit;
  private String yUnit;

  public LineFeatureBuilder(SimpleFeatureType type2) {
    super(type2);
    this.type = type2;
    formatter = new CoordinateFormat();
    formatter.setNumberPattern("##0.00");
    formatter.setAnglePattern("DD.dd");

    formatter.setCoordinateReferenceSystem(type.getCoordinateReferenceSystem());
    xFormat = formatter.getFormat(0);
    yFormat = formatter.getFormat(1);
    CoordinateSystem coordinateSystem = type.getCoordinateReferenceSystem().getCoordinateSystem();
    xUnit = "" + coordinateSystem.getAxis(0).getUnit().toString();
    yUnit = "" + coordinateSystem.getAxis(1).getUnit().toString();
  }

  @Override
  public void setAttributes(GridElement el, Map<String, Object> attributes) {
    if (el instanceof OrthoLine) {
      OrthoLine orthoLine = (OrthoLine) el;
      attributes.put(ID_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ++id);
      attributes.put(LEVEL_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, orthoLine.getLevel());

      Coordinate v0 = orthoLine.getVertices()[0];
      Double value = null;
      String label = "";
      if (orthoLine.getOrientation() == LineOrientation.HORIZONTAL) {
        value = v0.y;
        label = yFormat.format(v0.y) + yUnit;
      } else {
        value = v0.x;
        label = xFormat.format(v0.x) + xUnit;
      }
      attributes.put(VALUE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, value);
      attributes.put(VALUE_LABEL_NAME, label);

    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected an instance of OrthoLine");
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: What dependency do I have to add in my pom to use org.geotools.measure.CoordinateFormat?