# Labeling Ortolines with GeoTools

Tags: labeling, java, geotools, maps

I want to add labels with geocoordinates on the grid of the map. I have previously asked you this question and you have shared some code with me ([How can I label the coordinate position of the grid coordinate lines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311498/how-can-i-label-the-coordinate-position-of-the-grid-coordinate-lines)), but I had no time to try it before.
So, now I am trying to adapt this code as bellowe

But I have no got the positive resoult yet with this work and also I have no any errors... Am I doing somthing wrong? Could you at least describe the steps to create these labels, please..?

Comment: You need a text symbolizer

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot!  I don’t have enough words to express my gratitude for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LineFeatureBuilder` creates attributes called `value` and `label` which you can use in the display of the grid lines. `Value` is just the numeric value while `label` is formatted and has a unit symbol too.

To put the labels on screen you need to use a `TextSymbolizer` (see [the styling docs](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/render/style.html) for more details). More information of line labelling is best found in the [GeoServer documentation on SLD](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/lines.html).

```
    // "labelPoint" feature type style
    StyleBuilder sb = new StyleBuilder();
    FilterFactory2 ff = sb.getFilterFactory();

    // creation of the TextSymbolizer
    AnchorPoint anchorPoint =
            sb.createAnchorPoint(sb.literalExpression(0), sb.literalExpression(0));
    PointPlacement pointPlacement =
            sb.createPointPlacement(anchorPoint, null, sb.literalExpression(0));
    TextSymbolizer textSymbolizer =
            sb.createTextSymbolizer(
                    sb.createFill(Color.BLACK),
                    new Font[] {sb.createFont("Lucida Sans", 10), sb.createFont("Arial", 10)},
                    sb.createHalo(),
                    sb.attributeExpression("label"),
                    pointPlacement,
                    null);
    Style style = sb.createStyle();
    FeatureTypeStyle featureTypeStyle =
            sb.createFeatureTypeStyle(
                    "labelPoint", new Symbolizer[] {textSymbolizer, lineSymbolizer});
    style.featureTypeStyles().add(featureTypeStyle);
```