# Latitude labels location on map

Tags: labeling, latitude-longitude, geotools, position

Following [Label coordinate position of Grid lines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357606/label-coordinate-position-of-grid-lines)
 explanations I was able to create latitude lines every 10 degrees with labels.
The values of the latitudes are drawn following the prime meridian (0 longitude).

Is there a way to display the labels along meridians 30W and 30E without displaying them at the prime meridian?

How could I label latitudes every 30 degrees starting at 0 while keeping the latitude lines (parallels) drawn every 10 degrees?

I have looked in various articles about filters and rules, but I have not been able to find the answer to my questions.

**New version of code creating lat/lon graticule and labeling** :

```
public Layer getGraticuleLayer(MapContent map, ReferencedEnvelope bounds) {
          CoordinateReferenceSystem crs1 = map.getCoordinateReferenceSystem();
          SimpleFeatureType type = (SimpleFeatureType) GridUtilities.buildType(crs1);
                List<OrthoLineDef> lineDefs = Arrays.asList(
                        new OrthoLineDef(LineOrientation.VERTICAL, 2, 10.0),
                        new OrthoLineDef(LineOrientation.HORIZONTAL, 2,10.0));
                double vertexSpacing = 0.1;
                SimpleFeatureSource grid = 
             Lines.createOrthoLines(bounds, lineDefs, vertexSpacing, 
                new LineFeatureBuilder(type));
                Style blueStyle = SLD.createLineStyle(Color.blue, 1.0f);
                ((LineSymbolizer)blueStyle.featureTypeStyles().get(0).rules()
                        .get(0).symbolizers().get(0)).getStroke().setOpacity(ff.literal(0.5));
             FeatureLayer layer = new FeatureLayer(grid, blueStyle);
             ReferencedEnvelope gridBounds = layer.getBounds();
             StyleBuilder sb = new StyleBuilder();
             java.awt.Font font = java.awt.Font.decode("Arial");
             TextSymbolizer text = sb.createTextSymbolizer(Color.white,
                        sb.createFont(font), "label");
                // every 30 instead of 10
             String localElement = "element";
             for (OrthoLineDef lineDef : lineDefs) {
                 switch (lineDef.getOrientation()) {
                     case HORIZONTAL:
                         Rule rule = blueStyle.featureTypeStyles().get(0).rules().get(0);
                         Function startPoint = ff.function("startPoint", ff.property(localElement)); // name = localName var in orig code
                         Function endPoint = ff.function("endPoint", ff.property(localElement));  // name = localName var in orig code.
                         text.setGeometry(endPoint);
                         Filter filter = ff.and(ff.equals(ff.function("getY", startPoint), ff.function("getY", endPoint)), ff.equals(ff.function("IEEEremainder", ff.function("parseDouble", ff.property("value")), ff.literal(30)),
                                 ff.literal(0)));
                         rule.setFilter(filter);
                         LabelPlacement lp = sb.createPointPlacement(.5, .5, 0, -10, 0);
                         text.setLabelPlacement(lp);
                         rule.symbolizers().add(text);
                         break;
                     case VERTICAL:
                         Rule ruleLon = blueStyle.featureTypeStyles().get(0).rules().get(0);
                         startPoint = ff.function("startPoint", ff.property(localElement));
                         endPoint = ff.function("endPoint", ff.property(localElement));
                         text.setGeometry(endPoint);
                         filter = ff.and(ff.equals(ff.function("getX", startPoint), ff.function("getX", endPoint)), ff.equals(ff.function("IEEEremainder", ff.function("parseDouble", ff.property("value")), ff.literal(30)),
                                 ff.literal(0)));
                         ruleLon.setFilter(filter);
                         // text.setLabelPlacement(lp);
                         lp = sb.createPointPlacement(.5, .5, -10, 0, 90.0);
                         text.setLabelPlacement(lp);
                         ruleLon.symbolizers().add(text);
                         break;
                 }
             }
             Layer gridLayer = new FeatureLayer(grid, blueStyle);

             return gridLayer;

        }
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
        FeatureTypeStyle featureTypeStyle = sf.createFeatureTypeStyle();
        String geometryName = LineFeatureBuilder.DEFAULT_GEOMETRY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME;
         String labelName = LineFeatureBuilder.VALUE_LABEL_NAME;
         String valueName = LineFeatureBuilder.VALUE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME;

         Function startPoint = ff.function("startPoint", ff.property(geometryName));
         Function endPoint = ff.function("endPoint", ff.property(geometryName));
// Set up how the labels are drawn
         TextSymbolizer htext = sb.createTextSymbolizer(Color.red, sb.createFont(font), labelName);
         TextSymbolizer vtext = sb.createTextSymbolizer(Color.red, sb.createFont(font), labelName);
         htext.setGeometry(endPoint);
         vtext.setGeometry(endPoint);
         LabelPlacement hlp = sb.createPointPlacement(.5, .5, 10, 0, 0);
         LabelPlacement vlp = sb.createPointPlacement(.5, .5, 0, -50, 0);
         htext.setLabelPlacement(hlp);
         vtext.setLabelPlacement(vlp);

// create a rule for Horizontal Labels
         Rule rule = sb.createRule(htext);
         Filter hFilter = ff.and(ff.equals(ff.function("getY", startPoint), ff.function("getY", endPoint)), ff.equals(
                 ff.function("IEEEremainder", ff.function("parseInt", ff.property(valueName)), ff.literal(30)), ff.literal(0)));
         rule.setFilter(hFilter);
         featureTypeStyle.rules().add(rule);

         Filter vFilter = ff.and(ff.equals(ff.function("getX", startPoint), ff.function("getX", endPoint)), ff.equals(
                 ff.function("IEEEremainder", ff.function("parseInt", ff.property(valueName)), ff.literal(30)), ff.literal(0)));

         Rule ruleLon = sb.createRule(vtext);
         ruleLon.setFilter(vFilter);
         featureTypeStyle.rules().add(ruleLon);
//         blueStyle.featureTypeStyles().get(0).rules().get(0).symbolizers().add(text);  // replaced by rule.symbolizers(text)
         **blueStyle.featureTypeStyles().add(featureTypeStyle);**
         Layer gridLayer = new FeatureLayer(grid, blueStyle);
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to add a filter to your style that checked if the line was horizontal or vertical and if it is evenly divisible by 30.

So something like this (which is psuedocode):

```
y(startPoint("element")) == y(endPoint("element") and IEEERemainder("value",30) == 0
```

which becomes something like:

```
  Rule rule = red.featureTypeStyles().get(0).rules().get(0);
  Function startPoint = ff.function("startPoint", ff.property(localName));
  Function endPoint = ff.function("endPoint", ff.property(localName));
  text.setGeometry(endPoint);
  Filter filter = ff.and(ff.equals(ff.function("getY", startPoint), ff.function("getY", endPoint)),

      ff.equals(ff.function("IEEEremainder", ff.function("parseDouble", ff.property("value")), ff.literal(30)),
          ff.literal(0)));
  rule.setFilter(filter);
  // LabelPlacement lp = sb.createLinePlacement(ff.literal(4));
  // text.setLabelPlacement(lp);
  LabelPlacement lp = sb.createPointPlacement(.5, .5, 0, -10, 0);
  text.setLabelPlacement(lp);
  rule.symbolizers().add(text);
```

To give:

[image]

You need to create a 2nd `Rule` for the vertical grid lines and repeat the process for those.

### Update

It seems that the lines may not always be at the *exact* value I expected so `30.00000000000008 mod 30` is not 0, the answer to this is to use `parseInt` instead of `parseDouble` in the filters.

Also you need two text symbolizers and two rules (or otherwise the horizontal display changes when you set up the vertical one). So I came up with something like, though I still don't get the latitude labels until I move the map down and I'm not sure why:

```
String geometryName = LineFeatureBuilder.DEFAULT_GEOMETRY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME; // element
String labelName = LineFeatureBuilder.VALUE_LABEL_NAME; //label
String valueName = LineFeatureBuilder.VALUE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME; //value

Function startPoint = ff.function("startPoint", ff.property(geometryName));
Function endPoint = ff.function("endPoint", ff.property(geometryName));
// Set up how the labels are drawn
TextSymbolizer htext = sb.createTextSymbolizer(Color.red, sb.createFont(font), labelName);
TextSymbolizer vtext = sb.createTextSymbolizer(Color.red, sb.createFont(font), labelName);
htext.setGeometry(endPoint);
vtext.setGeometry(endPoint);
LabelPlacement hlp = sb.createPointPlacement(.5, .5, 10, 0, 0);
LabelPlacement vlp = sb.createPointPlacement(.5, .5, 0, -50, 0);
htext.setLabelPlacement(hlp);
vtext.setLabelPlacement(vlp);

// create a rule for Horizontal Labels
Rule rule = sb.createRule(htext);
Filter hFilter = ff.and(ff.equals(ff.function("getY", startPoint), ff.function("getY", endPoint)), ff.equals(
    ff.function("IEEEremainder", ff.function("parseInt", ff.property(valueName)), ff.literal(30)), ff.literal(0)));
rule.setFilter(hFilter);
featureTypeStyle.rules().add(rule);

Filter vFilter = ff.and(ff.equals(ff.function("getX", startPoint), ff.function("getX", endPoint)), ff.equals(
    ff.function("IEEEremainder", ff.function("parseInt", ff.property(valueName)), ff.literal(30)), ff.literal(0)));

Rule ruleLon = sb.createRule(vtext);
ruleLon.setFilter(vFilter);
featureTypeStyle.rules().add(ruleLon);

//writeStyle(blueStyle);
Layer gridLayer = new FeatureLayer(grid, blueStyle);
```

[image]

Comment: no latitude labels appear. After code above I have:          redStyle.featureTypeStyles().get(0).rules().get(0).symbolizers().add(text);
         Layer gridLayer = new FeatureLayer(grid, redStyle);  What am I missing?

Comment: `rule.symbolizers().add(text);` replaces `redStyle.featureTypeStyles().get(0).rules().get(0).symbolizers().add(text);`

Comment: That did not do it.  I think the issue is with "localName" variable used in Functions startPoint and endPoint.  What should be that set to exactly?

Comment: String localName = "element";

Comment: That setting, stops adding labels and lines completely.  Tried with lat rule and with lat/lon rule.Same result:     `code`   for (OrthoLineDef lineDef : lineDefs) {
             switch (lineDef.getOrientation()) {
                 case HORIZONTAL:
                     String localElement = "element";
                     Rule rule = blueStyle.featureTypeStyles().get(0).rules().get(0);
                     Function startPoint = ff.function("startPoint", ff.property(localElement)); 
                     Function endPoint = ff.function("endPoint", ff.property(localElement));  ....`code`

Comment: please [edit] the question to add your code

Comment: That line assumes you called you geometry "element" - if it's something else pick that instead

Comment: Tried Update code, but no labels yet in latitude or longitude.  See updated code in question.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is comment out the filter and see it it works then, and then either fix the other bits if it still doesn't work or fix the filter one part at a time if that is the issue. Failing that step through in an debugger to see what is happening

Comment: Added missing piece to show all labels in UPDATED CODE:        **blueStyle.featureTypeStyles().add(featureTypeStyle);**  Tried to make it bold but I did not succeed.  Labeling map works like a charm in JFrame as used in  https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/raster/image.html code, but missing longitude and  latitude labels at the end of lines when rendering MapContent to tiff using GTRenderer. Thank you Ian!!

Comment: Still cannot properly include longitude labels inside the map using startPoint or latitude labels using endPoint. Which are the units in the X and Y displacements in :LabelPlacement hlp = sb.createPointPlacement(.5, .5, 10, 0, 0);
LabelPlacement vlp = sb.createPointPlacement(.5, .5, 0, -50, 0);? i.e how can I compute the -50 for my map so I can see the label?

Comment: they are in pixels