# Exception when defining Grid lines, using OrthLine

Tags: geotools

I've tried Ian's solution for question: [Label coordinate position of Grid lines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357606/label-coordinate-position-of-grid-lines), but gets an exception when executing:

```
SimpleFeatureSource grid = Lines.createOrthoLines(gridBounds, lineDefs, vertexSpacing, new LineFeatureBuilder(type));
```

in context;

```
    ....
    SimpleFeatureType type = (SimpleFeatureType) GridUtilities.buildType(crs);
    List<OrthoLineDef> lineDefs = Arrays.asList(
       // vertical (longitude) lines
       new OrthoLineDef(LineOrientation.VERTICAL, 2, 10/*xStep*/),
       // horizontal (latitude) lines
       new OrthoLineDef(LineOrientation.HORIZONTAL, 2, 10/*yStep*/));

     // Specify vertex spacing to get "densified" polygons
     double vertexSpacing = 0.1;
     SimpleFeatureSource grid = Lines.createOrthoLines(gridBounds, lineDefs, vertexSpacing, new LineFeatureBuilder(type));
 ...
```

I can't solve this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such attribute:level
at org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureBuilder.set(SimpleFeatureBuilder.java:244)
at org.geotools.grid.ortholine.OrthoLineBuilder.doBuildLineFeatures(OrthoLineBuilder.java:201)
at org.geotools.grid.ortholine.OrthoLineBuilder.buildGrid(OrthoLineBuilder.java:93)
at org.geotools.grid.Lines.createOrthoLines(Lines.java:116)
```

LineFeatureBuilder.java

```
import java.text.Format;
import java.util.Map;
import org.geotools.grid.GridElement;
import org.geotools.grid.GridFeatureBuilder;
import org.geotools.grid.ortholine.LineOrientation;
import org.geotools.grid.ortholine.OrthoLine;
import org.geotools.referencing.CoordinateFormat;
//import org.geotools.measure.CoordinateFormat;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;
import org.opengis.referencing.cs.CoordinateSystem;

public class LineFeatureBuilder extends GridFeatureBuilder {
  /** Default feature TYPE name: "linegrid" */
  public static final String DEFAULT_TYPE_NAME = "linegrid";

  /** Name used for the integer id attribute: "id" */
  public static final String ID_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "id";

  /**
   * Name of the Integer level attribute ("level")
  */
  public static final String LEVEL_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "level";

  /**
   * Name of the Object value attribute ("value")
  */
  public static final String VALUE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "value";
  public static final String VALUE_LABEL_NAME = "label";
  protected int id;
  private SimpleFeatureType type;
  private CoordinateFormat formatter;
  private Format xFormat;
  private Format yFormat;
  private String xUnit;
  private String yUnit;

  public LineFeatureBuilder(SimpleFeatureType type2) {
     super(type2);
     this.type = type2;
     formatter = new CoordinateFormat();
     formatter.setNumberPattern("##0.00");
     formatter.setAnglePattern("DD.dd");

     formatter.setCoordinateReferenceSystem(type.getCoordinateReferenceSystem());
     xFormat = formatter.getFormat(0);
     yFormat = formatter.getFormat(1);
     CoordinateSystem coordinateSystem = 
       type.getCoordinateReferenceSystem().getCoordinateSystem();
       xUnit = "" + coordinateSystem.getAxis(0).getUnit().toString();
       yUnit = "" + coordinateSystem.getAxis(1).getUnit().toString();
 }

 @Override
 public void setAttributes(GridElement el, Map<String, Object> attributes) {
    if (el instanceof OrthoLine) {
       OrthoLine orthoLine = (OrthoLine) el;
       attributes.put(ID_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ++id);
       attributes.put(LEVEL_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, orthoLine.getLevel());
       Coordinate v0 = orthoLine.getVertices()[0];
       Double value = null;
       String label = "";
       if (orthoLine.getOrientation() == LineOrientation.HORIZONTAL) {
          value = v0.y;
          label = yFormat.format(v0.y) + yUnit;
       } else {
          value = v0.x;
          label = xFormat.format(v0.x) + xUnit;
       }
       attributes.put(VALUE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, value);
       attributes.put(VALUE_LABEL_NAME, label);
    } else {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected an instance of OrthoLine");
    }
 }
}
```

GridUtilities.java:

```
import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.LineString;
import org.opengis.feature.type.FeatureType;
import org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem;

public class GridUtilities {

   public static FeatureType buildType(CoordinateReferenceSystem crs) {
      SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder tb = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
      tb.setName("MapGrid");
      tb.add(LineFeatureBuilder.DEFAULT_GEOMETRY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, LineString.class, crs);
      tb.add("ATTRIBUTE_NAME", Integer.class);
      tb.add("LEVEL_ATTRIBUTE_NAME", Integer.class);
      tb.add("VALUE_LABEL_NAME", String.class);
      tb.add("VALUE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME", Double.class);
      return tb.buildFeatureType();
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: is there any more stack trace in the error?

Comment: Sorry, imported opengis.feature.. instead of geotools.feature....